# Algorithm on stacks

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

using the following algorithm

```
Begin  
    Initialize Stacks S1,S2
    Push all elements into Stack S1

Procedure P(){
    While(!S1.isEmpty())
    PushS2(PopS1())

}
While(!s2.isEmpty())
    Print(popS2())
End
```

Then it asks the question **what is the pseudo code above intended to do?What does the above algorithm works.**

I understand how stacks work. And here all it print outs is the same thing that was given as input.If `a,b,c,d,e` was input then it would print out `a,b,c,d,e`.

Does this algorithm represent anything significant.What's the use of writing this sort of one?

Comment: What is the procedure `P` definition doing in the middle of the block? That doesn't make sense to me. (One could even argue this would be invalid syntax, even in pseudocode.) Is this the whole question, or is `P` used elsewhere?

Comment: @Heuster This was a given algorithm and this is the whole question

Answer (score 0):

`P()` pushes everything from `S1` to `S2` by popping everything from `S1` and pushing it onto `S2` until the stack is empty and the ending `while` loop prints everything in S2 until that is empty... This seems pretty straight forward unless I am missing something.

`push()` adds an item to a stack.

`pop()` returns the top item from a stack.

Comment: :I understand what happens .I don't know what sort of answer i should give to the question what is the pseudo code above intended to do?What does the above algorithm works.

Comment: @sam_rox copy one stack to the another stack and print out what is in the stack... It will also reverse what is in S1... maybe that's what you're looking for

Comment: :It doesn't reverse once s2 is popped right?In s2 we have the reversed stack.But when it is popped it is no longer reversed

Comment: Well that depends on how number S1 and S2 are initialized but yes